Unsafe assignment of an `any` in NextAuth(options: AuthOptions)
I am getting a typescript/eslint error for the following piece of code in Next-Auth (4.24.6). How do I resolve this issue?
Unsafe assignment of an `any` value.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment
(alias) NextAuth(options: AuthOptions): any (+2 overloads)
import NextAuth

import NextAuth from "next-auth";

import { authOptions } from "@/server/auth";

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);
export { handler as GET, handler as POST };

